# integrating KATTA And SOLR using SOLR-1395

Tags: solr, katta

I am trying to use the patch provided for the integration of Katta and SOLR [SOLR-1395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1395)

Can anybody help me to figure out the versions of KATTA patch & Katta trunk to be used for this?

Currently i have used;
[**katta-80-1.patch**](http://oss.101tec.com/jira/browse/KATTA-80) with **Katta 0.6** trunk.

I am unable to apply the above patch, it gives me error while applying the patch.

Anyone who is worked on it, plesae help me to resolve this

Thanks
Vipin

Answer (score 2):

The Patch [KATTA-80](http://oss.101tec.com/jira/browse/KATTA-80) already seems to be applied to the Fixed version and Status resolved.
So I suppose the changes should already be included in the trunk version.

Also, the comment mentions `katta-80-1.patch works against trunk as of the date of the patch.` which was way back in 2009 !! So not sure if it can be applied now.

You can check the changes by opening the patch and applying it manually if you are able to find the files with no differences.

SOLR-1395 should be applicable on the trunk.
You can check for the revision number in the patch file to track it to the trunk revision number.

Comment: Hi Jayendra, Thanks for the quick response.
What about the SOLR patch?